# Typescript Union on Arrays of Objects

Tags: typescript

Fiddling around with a union of arrays which contains objects. Expected that TS is able to guard the correct type but I guess I am missing smth here:

```
type A = ReadonlyArray<
  | { readonly __typename: 'EmbedParagraph' }
  | { readonly __typename: 'EntityQueueParagraph' }
  | null
> | null;

type B = ReadonlyArray<
  | { readonly __typename: 'EmbedParagraph' }
  | {
      readonly __typename: 'EntityQueueParagraph';
      readonly id: string | null;
      readonly title: string | null;
    }
  | null
> | null;

function test(paragraphs: A | B) {
  paragraphs?.forEach((paragraph) => {
    /**
     * TS OUTPUT:
     * (parameter) paragraph: {
     *     readonly __typename: "EmbedParagraph";
     * } | {
     *     readonly __typename: "EntityQueueParagraph";
     * } | {
     *     readonly __typename: "EmbedParagraph";
     * } | {
     *     readonly __typename: "EntityQueueParagraph";
     *     readonly id: string | null;
     *     readonly title: string | null;
     * } | null
     */
    if (paragraph?.__typename === 'EntityQueueParagraph') {
      console.log(paragraph);
      /**
       * TS OUTPUT:
       * (parameter) paragraph: {
       *     readonly __typename: "EntityQueueParagraph";
       * }
       */
    }

    if (paragraph && 'id' in paragraph) {
      console.log(paragraph);
      /**
       * TS OUTPUT:
       * (parameter) paragraph: never
       */
    }
  });
}
```

My thought was, that after the `.__typename` check, there are both options available. But I am only able to use the entity queue defined in type `A`. Order does not seem to be the reason.

Same goes for the 2nd condition where I would expect that TS infers type `B` because the `id` field is only available there.

Hope you can give me a hint or a further read. Thanks a lot!
bw

**EDIT**
After adding a new key to type `A`s `EntityQueueParagraph` typing (added `foo: number`), TS is able to distinguish the two types... unfortunately not usable for my situation.

Comment: The first commented output is only of the first 2 objects from type `A` for me. Is it not the same for you?

Comment: no sry. my bad. it's the same as you mentioned. used the `.map` first instead of `.forEach` and didn't update the typings. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently with a `map`, instead of `forEach` you already have better inheritance. And changing from `paragraphs?.` to `paragraphs && paragraphs.` when checking the `__typename` fixed your issue.

```
type A = ReadonlyArray<
  | { readonly __typename: 'EmbedParagraph' }
  | { readonly __typename: 'EntityQueueParagraph' }
  | null
> | null;

type B = ReadonlyArray<
  | { readonly __typename: 'EmbedParagraph' }
  | {
      readonly __typename: 'EntityQueueParagraph';
      readonly id: string | null;
      readonly title: string | null;
    }
  | null
> | null;

function test(paragraphs: A | B) {
  paragraphs?.map((paragraph) => {
    if (paragraph && paragraph.__typename === 'EntityQueueParagraph') {
      console.log(paragraph);
    }

    if (paragraph && 'id' in paragraph) {
      console.log(paragraph);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: omg! could swear that i've tried that as well! thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'm still really confused why it doesn't work with `forEach`. You get the correct types with `.map`, `for...of` and a normal `for` loop, but not `forEach`